# AsyncListDiffer is not updating the recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils, android-asynclistdiffer

I have a RecyclerView with an adapter that uses *AssyncListDiffer*. The problem I have is that the recyclerview is **not updated** when changes happen in the LiveData. The observer is notified but the list doesn't update.

This is my adapter:

```
class HourAdapter(private val interaction: HourInteraction? = null) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<HourAdapter.HourViewHolder>() {

    private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, DIFF_CALLBACK)

    fun submitList(list: List<Hour>?) {
        differ.submitList(list)
    }

    private fun getHourAt(position: Int): Hour {
        return differ.currentList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HourViewHolder {...}

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HourViewHolder, position: Int) {...}

    val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Hour>() {

      override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Hour, newItem: Hour): Boolean {
        return (oldItem.name == newItem.name) && (oldItem.isChecked == newItem.isChecked)
        }

      override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Hour, newItem: Hour): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
       }

     }

    class HourViewHolder
        (
        internal val binder: HourItemBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binder.root)

}
```

I use the "*submitList()*" to submit the new list. But it **doesn't work**.

I looked for solutions online and basically there were 2 options:

1. In the *submitList* function, call the "submitList" of AssyncListDiffer twice like this:

   ````
       differ.submitList(null)
       differ.submitList(list)
   }```
   ````
2. The second option was to use *ListAdapter* and override the "submitList" function like this:

```
  override fun submitList(list: List<Hour>?) {
  super.submitList(list?.let { ArrayList(it) })
  }
```

The first solution works, but the recyclerview **blinks** whenever I update it.
The second solution to override the method does not work for me.

I've been trying to fix this for days, but I can't make it work. Also, I don't want to use notifyItemChanged() or notifyDataSetChanged().

Is there another way?

Comment: did you try differ.submitList(list) to differ.submitList(list.toMutableList())?

Comment: @CôngHải I just did and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you attach code inside DiffUtils

Comment: @CôngHải Just edited the question.

Comment: Where you are calling `submitlist` function? inside where?

Comment: @CôngHải I am calling it inside the observer of the Livedata.

Comment: @CyberUser did you get any solution for it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I came around the same thing and observed the following.

Each time `AsyncListDiffer` received my list; it was the same object as previously - present in memory. Hence, the differ decided nothing changed and did not submit the updated list.

My list contained one object inside, and for each submission attempt I was changing one field. The object and the list of course remained the same.

So, I wondered why option number 2 did not work, and turned out that I needed to be a little more expressive:

```
submitList(it.map {
    it.copy()
})
```

Otherwise, **Kotlin would not make a deep copy of the object.**

Comment: Interesting solution. I tried your way. Instead of the whole list blinking, now only the item being clicked blinks. The problem though is that the change does not appear in the item. Whenever I click the recycler view item, it should mark the checkbox. But it doesn't. I ended up using notifyItemChanged().

Comment: I think it may help to see the implementation for the click handler and onBindViewHolder() then, if you don't mind to continue of course ;)

Answer (score 0):

The central question regarding why the `AsyncListDiffer` is not updating the items when a new list is submitted [has been answered already by pratclot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990660/11671103): modifying the previously-submitted list in memory and resubmitting it will not trigger the `AsyncListDiffer` to check if items are the same or not—it has to be a different list object.

However, I wanted to answer the other question, as I just ran into this issue myself and stumbled upon your question in trying to find a solution to the visual issue you shared:

> The first solution works, but the recyclerview blinks whenever I update it.

As you mentioned in the comments to pratclot's answer, when I would submit a new copy of the list to the `AsyncListDiffer`, it results in just that one item disappearing & reappearing rather than the whole list. It is an unattractive look!

The reason for this is because by default, the `RecyclerView` has a `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator` active on it. This will animate the `ViewHolders` in four circumstances: added, removed, changed, and moved.

In this case, we are dealing with the changed animation. Therefore, the solution is to simply deactivate the animation when a change occurs to an item. If you have not given the `RecyclerView` a custom `ItemAnimator`, then you can simply cast it to `DefaultItemAnimator` to accomplish this:

```
(recyclerView.itemAnimator as DefaultItemAnimator).supportsChangeAnimations = false
```

If this does not work and the items still blink or fade out/in, it means that `AsyncListDiffer.areItemsTheSame()` logic is incorrect for your use case. If this returns false, the item will experience removing and adding animations. Only `AsyncListDiffer.areContentsTheSame()` equating to false will result in the changing animation.

Additionally, please note that you can modify `ItemAnimator` properties `changeDuration`, `addDuration`, `moveDuration`, and `removeDuration` to specify how quickly (in milliseconds) you want these animations to occur. By setting them all to `0`, you can effectively remove all animations, not just the change ones. There may be certain use cases for such an approach.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to delete a row and had the same problem, but solved it with the following:

The below code is added in the fragment:

```
private void deleteRow(int position) {
        ArrayList<Card> cardsArrayList = adapter.getArrayList();
        cardsArrayList.remove(position);
        adapter.submitList(cardsArrayList);
    }
```

And this code is in the adapter:

```
public ArrayList<Card> getArrayList(){
        List<Card> cardList = mDiffer.getCurrentList();
        return new ArrayList<>(cardList) ;
    }
```